# Does arcane ward come back after a polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, polymorph

In the description of *polymorph*, it states that

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.

And this [sage advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/page/2/?s=polymorph) clarifies the meaning of "game statistics", which are meant to also include class features.

So it seems reasonable to interpret this as to say that an abjuration wizard does not have Arcane Ward up while under the effect of a *polymorph* spell, since it is a class feature. But when the wizard reverses to their original form, does the Arcane Ward come back up?

By the description in the PHB, p.115, there is a relevant remark:

> Once you create the ward, you can't create it again until you finish a long rest.

which suggests that it *can* end by some method. So when the effect of *polymorph* ends, does the wizard no longer have Arcane Ward up, therefore having to wait until the next long rest to be able to raise it again, or does it return in the same situation as immediately before *polymorph* entered into effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Polymorph does not interrupt Arcane Ward

When polymorphed you can keep Arcane Ward going.

Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer, gave [this unofficial ruling](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/788143618083082240):

> If an abjuration wizard with arcane ward polymorphs into a beast, does he retain the arcane ward?
>
> If you're protected by Arcane Ward, changing your form doesn't end the ward, unless the transformation effect says otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

You are mistaking the class feature (that cannot be accessed while polymorphed) with the **effect** of said feature.

If you are polymorphed, you won't be able to **create** the ward, even if you could cast an abjuration spell while polymorphed.

But the **already created** ward will last until you finish a long rest. If the new form is able to cast abjuration spells, you can recharge the ward normally.